# How to setup heterogeneous replication with tungsten?

Tags: mysql, oracle, replication, tungsten-replicator

Recently i am working on a replication between heterogeneous dbs with [Tungsten Replicator](http://code.google.com/p/tungsten-replicator/). We have a mysql master and an oracle slave. According to the docs such a setup should work. I am using tungsten-replicator-2.0.5. I call

```
$TUNGSTEN_HOME/tools/configure \
    --verbose \
    --home-directory=$INSTALL_HOME \
    --cluster-hosts=$MA_HOST,$SL_HOST \
```

on the master node for creating a basic installation on both nodes. Note: using the installer (as recommended) fails, due to the heterogeneous setup, since the installer fails to find a mysql instance on the slave node. The replicator instances are configured by adding static-$SERVICENAME.properties to the conf directory and modifying conf/services.properties (replicator.host=$HOSTNAME, replicator.masterListenPortStart=12112, replicator.rmi_port=20000).

Launching the replicators resulted in an ORA-01850 when issuing an update statement against trep_commit_seqno in the tungsten schema, due to a missing 'timestamp' keyword in the SQL-Statement. Just in order to get beyond this error, i altered datatype of update_timestamp and extract_timestamp to varchar. The replicators are now starting up und some simple inserts where replicated but when the test script issues a

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1;
```

replication fails due to an ORA-00933, because of the 'IF EXISTS' clause. I am not sure if this is an error in my configuration or if tungsten in general has problems with the differences in DDL statements between those two products. Has somebody successfully set up a similar replication using tungsten?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Tungsten docuemntation has some useful guidance.  In particular, this point from the "Advanced Principles of Operation" is relevant: "Also, DDL statements beyond the simplest CREATE TABLE expressions are rarely at all portable. ".  In your case, `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1;` is not valid Oracle DDL.

[Read it here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/releases.continuent.com/doc/tungsten-1.3.2/html/Tungsten-Replicator-Guide/content/ch04s04.html).

Comment: Thank you for answering and pointing to the information. I think, i need to implement a filter for my purposes.

Comment: @MithunSasidharan - you shouldn't beg for points, it's not dignified.

Answer (score 2):

For anybody who is interested: Up to now, Tungsten does not perform any transformation of ddl statements in a heterogeneous environment (as MithunSasidharan wrote). Now i wrote a custom filter, that skips ddl statements using regular expressions. For synchronizing the schema defition, we will use [Apache DdlUtils](http://db.apache.org/ddlutils/), which serves quite well for transforming a schema definition between mysql and oracle. I assume it works for other vendors similarly well. Thanks.